# How to use COALESCE in WHERE in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the scenario where I have a dataset like so, and I need a Coalesce as to speak, within the WHERE clause.

The requirement is to filter where if there is a row with Type Actual, filter out the type of Expected. Please see dataset below which should make things clearer

**Table**
*Parent Record* (GUID), *Type* (text), *Date* (datetime)

**Actual Data**

1. 100, ABC Active, 01/01/2010
2. 100, ABC Draft, 01/01/2010
3. 100, DEF Draft, 01/01/2010
4. 100, GHI Active, 01/01/2010
5. 100, GHI Draft, 01/01/2010

**Expected Results**

1. 100, ABC Active, 01/01/2010
2. 100, DEF Draft, 01/01/2010
3. 100, GHI Active, 01/01/2010

As you can see, where there is a row with type `Active`, for a certain type, then the `Draft` is removed. If there is no type with an `Active` row, then just show the `Draft`.

could someone please help with the WHERE clause for this

Comment: Apologies - *update*. Actual > Active, Expected > Draft

Comment: *[edit]* your question if you want to edit/change/augment it.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `coalesce`, `case` etc in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Give us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.-

Comment: I cannot tell what the columns are in your sample data.

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need conditional ordering :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by ParentRecord, col
                            order by (case when Type = 'Active'
                                           then 1 
                                           else 2
                                      end)
                           );
```

This assumes `type` column doesn't have a other data like you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You want filtering . . . but I don't see where `coalesce()` comes in.  One way to do what you want is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'Active'
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'Draft' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.guid = t.guid);
```

You can express this in a single query as:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.type = 'Active') or
      (t.type = 'Draft' and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.guid = t.guid)
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler if the 'Active' and 'Draft' status were stored in a separate column since this would avoid taking sub-strings in the Type column.  There's actually not much in the WHERE clause.

Using a temp table for example:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (GUID int, Type varchar(100), Date datetime)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES
 (100, 'ABC Active', '01/01/2010'), (100, 'ABC Draft', '01/01/2010')
,(100, 'DEF Draft', '01/01/2010'), (100, 'GHI Active', '01/01/2010')
,(100, 'GHI Draft', '01/01/2010'), (100, 'JKL Active', '01/01/2010')

SELECT T.GUID
      ,COALESCE( (SELECT T2.Type
                    FROM @temp T2
                   WHERE T2.GUID = T.GUID
                     AND T2.Type LIKE '%Active'
                     AND LEFT(T.Type, 3) = LEFT(T2.Type, 3)
                  ) 
                   , T.Type
                ) AS [Type]
      ,T.Date
  FROM @temp T
 WHERE T.Type LIKE '%Draft'
```

Produces the expected output:

```
GUID    Type         Date
100     ABC Active   2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
100     DEF Draft    2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
100     GHI Active   2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
```